# ContentPresenter Not Always Working in Silverlight Template

Tags: xaml, silverlight, templates, controltemplate, contentpresenter

When we customize certain controls through a ControlTemplate, the ContentPresenter does not render the control as it should. Why is this?

Comment: That's because there is something wrong.

Comment: That is not an answer! And why the downvote?

Comment: Ok sorry, that wasn't helpful. I would honestly like to help. But I can't. You state that after you changed a ControlTemplate the content of some ContentPresenter won't render as expected. Neither did you provide the relevant parts of one of the affected ControlTemplates, nor the ContentPresenter that is misbehaving, so I have no chance to see how its properties are set (to see for example if there is an additional ContentTemplate set), you don't even clarify what "not render as it should" precisely mean: does it only render partially/clipped? not at all? The question is far too vague a.t.m.

Comment: "Does not render the control means exactly that". What I said matches my problem. In some cases, it seems that ContentPresenter does not do its job, so I ask, what are the requirements for it to work?

Comment: Well, share one of those cases with us. I have an idea what might be the problem. I don't want to troll, I tend to be rather snippy when I think the OP holds back relevant information unnecessarily.

Comment: For example, I have a RadGridView (Telerik Silverlight UI) *instance* where I defined a template that includes another ContentPresenter. The ContentPresenter does not render anything. I also tried with another RadGridView, but it is tricky to pass all properties to it, and I cannot do that with Columns. Anyway, what might be a possible cause?

Answer (score 0):

It would really be easier if you let me see the affected xaml markup. My idea on what might be the problem is based on the rather dirty default behavior of the ContentPresenter: when it is used inside the ControlTemplate of a ContentControl, it will automagically bind to the Content and ContentTemplate properties. But it won't do this for any other control type. And therefore has to be done explicitly.

Do you have those bindings set:

```
<ControlTemplate ...>
    ...
    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ...}"
      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ...}" />
    ...
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Doesn't work because RadGridView does not have a Content property (it isn't a ContentControl).

Comment: Do you plan to reveal one day, which properties you _are_ binding your ContentPresenter against?